# ASP.NET 5 Adding MVC6 Unit Test Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add Unit Test Project to a ASP.NET 5 Solution.

I've added  ASP.NET 5 class library project and referenced the required packaes in my project.json as below :-

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "xunit.runners": "1.0.0-alpha3",
        "Moq": "4.2.1502.911",
        "xunit": "2.0.0-rc4-build2924"

    },
    "commands": {
        "test": "Xunit.KRunner"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "net451": {
            "dependencies": {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to reference a to an attrivute of Xunit in a class file as follows :-

using Xunit;

```
namespace LondonUnderground.UnitTests
{
    public class RoutesTests
    {

        [Fact]
        public void TestShizz()
        {

        }


    }
}
```

I'm getting an error, telling me that i need the System.Runtime version 4.0.0.0 in order to access "Attribute" class.

If i try adding a reference to this in the project.json file, it  installs System.Runtime 4.0.20.0 Beta.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my project.json that works with tests.

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "xunit": "2.1.0-beta1-*",
        "xunit.runner.aspnet": "2.1.0-beta1-*"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {

            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22523"
            }
        }
    },
    "commands": {
        "test": "xunit.runner.aspnet"
    }
}
```